# Hide extra data in select field?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I am dynamically generating a select drop-down menu and was curious if there was a viable option to include additional information, perhaps a related database ID into the option value of the form. I am handling all the data flow using Javascript/Ajax and would like to know if this is possible in order to save database resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if no other way you can put db id as value . user will not see that.

```
 <option value="CA+":"id+":"+something >California -- CA </option>
```

data manipulation depends on you - explode or split the value of option

anyway ..does not look good. !!!

Comment: Awesome, I don't even need the value so I might as well go this route, thanks!